# @synthesize is not working and basic operations are not working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, text, integer, label, synthesizer

I am unsure why this code will not work. When I click a button (action: buttonclick) it should change the two text boxes' (MyTextLabel and MyTextLabel2) text increment value "r" by one. Here is the code:

```
MainView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MainView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UIButton *MyButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *MyTextLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *MyTextLabel2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *MyButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *MyTextLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *MyTextLabel2;


- (IBAction)buttonclick;
@end
```

MainView.m:

```
#import "MainView.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libc.h>

@implementation MainView

@synthesize MyButton, MyTextLabel, MyTextLabel2;

int r;

- (IBAction)buttonclick {
    r++
    if(r < 50) {
        MyTextLabel.text = @"< 50";
    }
    else {
        MyTextLabel2.text = @"=> 50";
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling something's wrong with the way you're using `int r`. Try putting `static int r;` at the top of the `@interface` line in MainView.h and also add, under the `- (IBAction)buttonclick;` line:

```
+(void) initialize;
```

Then remove `int r;` from MainView.m. Then in MainView.m add:

```
+(void) initialize {
   count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just make r a real ivar: add it to the variables declared in the @interface, initialize it to 0 in -init, and then increment it in buttonClick.

Comment: Oh, that's another way of doing it :)

Comment: @Sixten Otto: you don't need to use initialize r. It is set to 0 in the alloc.

Comment: @Abizern I just knew someone was going to jump on that. :-) Yes, the runtime will zero out ivars when allocating the memory, so that part isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help but now it says "expected special-qualifier-list before static" under the "#import "MainView.h" line. it also says that "r" is still undeclared!

Comment: YAY! I finally figured it out! all I had to do was declare "int r" in the @property line! ahh im such an idiot in objective-c!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1. You can't declare `int r` where you have it. You should declare it in your interface's variable block (where you declare your button and labels or outside a method) or in the method definition.
2. The line with r++ isn't ended with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say in your question what, exactly, isn't working the way you expect it. My guess is going to be that your outlets aren't actually connected properly. You might want to add a log statement to `buttonClick` like this:

```
NSLog(@"button click called! MyTextLabel is %@", MyTextLabel);
```

The point being, mostly, to be sure it isn't `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, for not telling! The code stalls and stops on opening the app and in the code it stops on the "@synthesize"

Comment: Can you add the stack trace in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C the names of variables and properties must start with a lowercase letter to conform to the Key-Value Coding (KVC) protocol (always myButton, never MyButton). The `@synthesize` directive relies on this to generate the setters and getters. Thus, for `myButton` `@synthesize` will generate `-(void)setMyButton:(UIButton *)button` and `-(UIButton *)myButton`.

So, do make `MyButton` and its colleagues lowercase and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Action methods always have a sender argument, so your `-buttonClick:` method should be declared like this:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClick: (id)sender {
}
```